# Can we know if a collection is almost sorted without applying a sort algorithm?

Tags: bubble-sort, sorting

In the wikipedia article on sorting algorithms,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms
 under Bubble sort it says:*Bubble sort can also be used efficiently on a list of any length that is nearly sorted (that is, the elements are not significantly out of place)*

So  my question is: Without sorting the list using a sorting algoithm first, how can one know if *that is nearly sorted* or not?

Comment: Iterate once, count the number of pairs that are out of order?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the general sorting lower bound? You can prove that in a comparison-based sorting algorithm, any sorting algorithm must make Ω(n log n) comparisons in the average case. The way you prove this is through an information-theoretic argument. The basic idea is that there are n! possible permutations of the input array, and since the only way you can learn about which permutation you got is to make comparisons, you have to make at least lg n! comparisons in order to be certain that you know the structure of your input permutation.

I haven't worked out the math on this, but I suspect that you could make similar arguments to show that it's difficult to learn how sorted a particular array is. Essentially, if you don't do a large number of comparisons, then you wouldn't be able to tell apart an array that's mostly sorted from an array that is actually quite far from sorted. As a result, all the algorithms I'm aware of that measure "sortedness" take a decent amount of time to do so.

For example, one measure of the level of "sortedness" in an array is the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) in that array. You can count the number of inversions in an array in time O(n log n) using a divide-and-conquer algorithm based on mergesort, but with that runtime you could just sort the array instead.

Typically, the way that you'd know that your array was mostly sorted was to know something a priori about how it was generated. For example, if you're looking at temperature data gathered from 8AM - 12PM, it's very likely that the data is already mostly sorted (modulo some variance in the quality of the sensor readings). If your data looks at a stock price over time, it's also likely to be mostly sorted unless the company has a really wonky trajectory. Some other algorithms also partially sort arrays; for example, it's not uncommon for quicksort implementations to stop sorting when the size of the array left to sort is small and to follow everything up with a final insertion sort pass, since every element won't be very far from its final position then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there exists any standardized measure of how sorted or random an array is.

You can come up with your own measure - like count the number of adjacent pairs which are out of order (suggested in comment), or count the number of larger numbers which occur before smaller numbers in the array (this is trickier than a simple single pass).